# I am new to programming and I have faced a dilemma

Tags: python

I have begun programming and I have faced a dilemma that do I need to learn everything about a particular language or do i need to learn the main concepts

Comment: You can not learn everything without learnings the main concepts. How is this a dilemma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to learn literally everything about a programming language. Using python for example, there are so many packages, and new ones packages are being developed every week, nobody knows them all. It's more important to know the main concept. If you're using python for data science, for example, you'll need to know Numpy, pandas, matplotlib, scikit learn as your basics.

Comment: External packages are not part of the language.